# Twitter Bootstrap modal resizing page on show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that uses modals. It seems that on any browser, when I click the icons (upload links) the modal pops down and then the page shrinks a little to the left.

Live example here: http://dev.handyvet.org/VetProsDevSite/_MASTER/views/vetpro%20users/vet_pro_registration_1.html

Why is this happening?

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>VetPro Registration</title>

    <!-- Style Css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/fonts/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="split-background">
    <!-- Start Header -->
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="text-center">
          <a href="../static pages/home.html"><img src="../../assets/images/Center-Logo.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- End Header -->

    <!-- Start Body -->
    <h3 class="page-header">New VetPro Registration</h3>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="vetpro-registration">
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="form" role="form">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1" id="personal_info">
          <h4 class="text-left col-md-6 buffer">
              Personal Information (1 of 4)
          </h4>

          <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first_name"><span class="red"> * </span>Full Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="first_name" 
                           name="first_name"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="John Doe"
                           required />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="full_address"><span class="red"> * </span>Address</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="full_address" 
                           name="full_address"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="123 Example St, Town, Oregon 97000"
                           autocomplete="on"
                           onFocus="geolocate()"
                           required />
                  </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="address_2">Apt/Suite #</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="address_2" 
                           name="address_2"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="AP #104"
                           autocomplete="on"
                           required />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone"><span class="red"> * </span>Phone</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="phone" 
                           name="phone"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="(123) 345-1234"
                           required />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email"><span class="red"> * </span>Email</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="email" 
                           name="email"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="example@example.com"
                           required />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="service_branch"><span class="red"> * </span>Service Branch</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <select class="form-control"
                            name="service_branch"
                            id="service_branch"
                            required>
                      <option value="AF">Air Force</option>
                      <option value="AR">Army</option>
                      <option value="MR">Marines</option>
                      <option value="NV">Navy</option>
                      <option value="CG">Coast Guard</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="hat_size"><span class="red"> * </span>Hat Size</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <select class="form-control" 
                           name="hat_size"
                           id="hat_size" 
                           required>
                      <option value="Small">S</option>
                      <option value="Medium">M</option>
                      <option value="Large">L</option>
                      <option value="Extra Large">XL</option>
                      <option value="Extra Extra Large">XXL</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="shirt_size"><span class="red"> * </span>Shirt Size</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <select class="form-control" 
                           name="shirt_size"
                           id="shirt_size" 
                           required>
                      <option value="Small">S</option>
                      <option value="Medium">M</option>
                      <option value="Large">L</option>
                      <option value="Extra Large">XL</option>
                      <option value="Extra Extra Large">XXL</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="dob"><span class="red"> * </span>Date of Birth</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           data-provide="datepicker"
                           id="dob" 
                           name="dob"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="01/01/1980"
                           required />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="service_radius"><span class="red"> * </span>Service Radius</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
                    <select class="form-control"
                            name="state"
                            id="state"
                            required>
                      <option value="5">5 miles</option>
                      <option value="10">10 miles</option>
                      <option value="15">15 miles</option>
                      <option value="20">20 miles</option>
                      <option value="25">25 miles</option>
                      <option value="30">30 miles</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bio"><span class="red"> * </span>Biography</label>
                <textarea class="form-control"
                     id="bio" 
                     name="bio"
                     required /></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="avatar"><span class="red"> * </span>Avatar</label>
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#avatar_upload">
                    <img src="../../assets/images/NewVetProRegisterAvatar.jpg" class="avatar-upload">
                    <p>Upload Image</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div id="avatar_upload" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Important!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Please be certain that your avatar photo is a "headshot" only! Do not include other people, your pets or a full body shot. Your image should be clear, recent, casual (no military uniform) & cropped from just above your head to just below your shoulders.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <input id="image" 
                             name="image" 
                             class="col-md-offset-4"
                             type="file" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="dd_214"><span class="red"> * </span>DD-214</label>
                  <br>
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#document_upload">
                    <img src="../../assets/images/DocumentIcon.jpg" class="document-upload">
                    <p>Upload Document</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div id="document_upload" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Important!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>As proof of time served, please upload a digital copy of your DD-214. If you have a physical copy, simply capture a clear photo with your smart-phone and upload the image. If lost, a new copy can be obtained from http://www.dd214.com.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <input id="document" 
                             name="document" 
                             class="col-md-offset-4"
                             type="file" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <a href="../static pages/home.html" type="button" class="btn btn-save">Save / Continue Later</a>
          <a href="vet_pro_registration_2.html" type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next &rarr;</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End Body -->

    <footer class="container-fluid">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Hire a hero</h1>
        <p>for help around your home or office</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-left">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
          <h4>Quick Links</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Become a VetPro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Customer Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">View our VetPros</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
          <h4>Reference</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services offered</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
          <h4>Contacts</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  $('#dob').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
  });

  var placeSearch, autocomplete;

  function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('full_address')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    document.getElementById('full_address').value = place.formatted_address.replace(", USA", "");
  }

  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCuqqRyIQcvB2Hzd7VKgdSphWfFuWh40kI&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/javascripts/forms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/javascripts/header.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a boostrap page using modals and resolved by simply offsetting the change with this in my custom CSS file.

```
.modal-open {
padding-right: 17px;
}
```

If that doesn't work specifically on your page, it is a documented issue and perhaps another fix can be found for you in the git thread: [link to thread](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15229)

Comment: It did not resolve it, but +1 for pointing me in the right direction